# Can a private store support the Android App Bundle format?

Tags: android, google-play, apk-expansion-files, android-app-bundle

My app is both on Google play store and on company's private store.

Sadly after importing a new library (40 mb of aar extension) the apk's size is grown over 100mb, also with shrink and minify enabled. 
I thought to use apk expansion, but I have read that is only for resource and not for executable code. I suppose only way is Android App Bundle, but the question is:

Is there a way to use aab format on private store ?

What do you suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of other stores supporting the AAB today, however this shouldn't prevent you from using AAB since you can generate a universal APK using bundletool which you can publish on other stores. You will soon be able to download this universal APK straight from the Play Console as well for convenience.

Comment: I'm worried about app testing, because the tester should test two different app instead one, because the automatic test coverage only a little part of the app :/